# Styling Custom Views

Tags: android, xml, custom-view, android-custom-view

I have a few custom views in my Android project and I've added the relevant details to the attrs.xml file. And now I can implement my objects through XML. This works fine.

How do I style these elements? When I try to use my custom attributes in the styles.xml is get an error "No resource found that matches the given name:"

For using the custom views in normal xml developement I use xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/bla.bla.bla". What is the correct for use in styles?

This is what my style looks like currently

```
<style name="Journey_DaySelect_Sunday">
    <item name="app:onImage">@drawable/day_sunday_selected</item>
    <item name="app:offImage">@drawable/day_sunday</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After more intensive searching on Google I gave up finding it answered elsewhere, and **by chance** tried using the absolute namespace of my generated R file it worked. May this solve all your problems.

### USE THE NAMESPACE CONTAINING YOUR R FILE

```
<style name="Journey_DaySelect_Sunday" parent="Journey_DaySelect">
    <item name="AppZappy.NIRailAndBus:onImage">@drawable/day_sunday_selected</item>
    <item name="AppZappy.NIRailAndBus:offImage">@drawable/day_sunday</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Looked everywhere to find the answer.

Comment: STOP YELLING AT ME

Answer (score 2):

For clarification, the item's name attribute should be the same as what is in the attrs.xml's declare-styleable name attribute + ":" + the attribute name.

For example:

attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>  
    <declare-styleable name="com.chuck.norris">
        <attr name="actionBarTextColor" format="color"/>
    </declare-styleable> 
</resources>
```

style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="myNewStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFF0000</item>
        <item name="com.chuck.norris:actionBarTextColor">#ffff0000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

You can then apply this style to all activities by using a theme in your manifest.xml file. Anywhere that a custom view exists that wants to use the "actionBarTextColor" attribute, you can then use the Java code:

```
TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrSet, R.styleable.com_chuck_norris);
COLOR_ACTION_BAR_TEXT = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.com_chuck_norris_actionBarTextColor, 0xff0000ff);
typedArray.recycle();
```

I'm not sure why you cannot just define your schema in your style.xml file as was asked above, but it seems to be a limitation of style.xml.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. Gradle complains that `com.chuck.norris:actionBarTextColor` cannot be found when you try to build the project. Using the plain `actionBarTextColor` works though.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
<style name="Journey_DaySelect_Sunday">
<item name="onImage">@drawable/day_sunday_selected</item>
<item name="offImage">@drawable/day_sunday</item>
</style>
```

[reference(Chinese)](http://blog.csdn.net/iispring/article/details/50708044)

if you guys think it useful,I will translate it.